# rendering new line (\n) as it is in react / html

Tags: html, reactjs, newline

I am trying to render new line characters as \n but they're being automatically converted to new lines.

```
const text = "hi\nhi"
<div>{text}</div>
```

This is being rendered as:

```
hi
hi
```

How can I actually show the text as "hi\nhi" without any formatting in react/html? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use double backslash, `"hi\\nhi"`, instead of `"hi\nhi"`.